# Need help on sed/awk command shell script for checking Sybase Errorlog

Tags: shell, awk, sed, hp-ux

I have been using shell script written by great expert of Sybase Mr. Rob Verschoor posted [here](http://www.sypron.nl/chklog.html). This job is called through cron job every hour and it sends email to us in case any keyword matches with the pre-defined keyword in the errorlog. To make the reference easy, I am posting the code below which could be causing the issue:

```
 LAST_MARKER=$(${AWK} '/'$MARKER'/ { a=NR } END { print a }' $LOGFILE_COPY)
  LAST_MARKER=`echo "$LAST_MARKER+0"|bs`
 if [ ! "$LAST_MARKER" = "" ]
   then
      sed "1,${LAST_MARKER}d" $LOGFILE_COPY > $TMP.x
      cp $TMP.x $LOGFILE_COPY
   fi
```

This had been working flawlessly from past 2 years without any issue with just one additional line after line no. from my side as below:

```
LAST_MARKER=`echo "$LAST_MARKER+0"|bs`
```

This was to format number of lines returned in proper number format as it was coming in scientific format.

It seems to have issue in finding last marker from last few days after we have disabled one monitoring tool which was filling up error log with trace messages almost every seconds. So, basically from last marker to new marker - we used to have so many lines of entries and never faced any issue. Now, after disabling this tool - in the non-working hour, there is no activity and hence last marker and new markers are becoming subsequent lines.

Earlier, it errorlog used to look like below with so many messages:

```
00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 10:15:59.92 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 10:15:59.92 server  _Marker_End_
...
0:0002:00000:00608:2020/04/16 11:12:40.88 server  DBCC TRACEON 3604, SPID 608
00:0002:00000:00608:2020/04/16 11:12:40.88 server  DBCC TRACEOFF 3604, SPID 608
00:0006:00000:00660:2020/04/16 11:13:40.47 server  DBCC TRACEON 3604, SPID 660
00:0006:00000:00660:2020/04/16 11:13:40.47 server  DBCC TRACEOFF 3604, SPID 660
00:0006:00000:00664:2020/04/16 11:13:40.51 server  DBCC TRACEON 3604, SPID 664
00:0006:00000:00664:2020/04/16 11:13:40.51 server  DBCC TRACEOFF 3604, SPID 664
00:0002:00000:00608:2020/04/16 11:13:40.54 server  DBCC TRACEON 3604, SPID 608
00:0002:00000:00608:2020/04/16 11:13:40.54 server  DBCC TRACEOFF 3604, SPID 608
00:0006:00000:00660:2020/04/16 11:13:40.87 server  DBCC TRACEON 3604, SPID 660
00:0006:00000:00660:2020/04/16 11:13:40.87 server  DBCC TRACEOFF 3604, SPID 660
00:0004:00000:00608:2020/04/16 11:14:40.92 server  DBCC TRACEOFF 3604, SPID 608
...
00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 11:15:59.92 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 11:15:59.92 server  _Marker_End_
```

Now, errorlog looks like below:

```
    00:0004:00000:00974:2020/04/17 09:15:28.80 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
    00:0004:00000:00974:2020/04/17 09:15:38.80 server  _Marker_End_
    00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 10:15:59.92 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
    00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 10:15:59.92 server  _Marker_End_
    00:0003:00000:00030:2020/04/17 11:16:01.51 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
    00:0003:00000:00030:2020/04/17 11:16:01.51 server  _Marker_End_
```

This tool is not able to distinguish between previous markers and last marker and hence sending even those errors again and again which occurred 3-4 hours ago whereas it was supposed to send no error mail as nothing is written in the errorlog in last one hour.

I am not expert in shell scripting; so, any help on this will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Correct behavior of this tool is to send email like below at 4:15(schedule time) because pre-defined matching keywords were there in last hour(between 3:15 and 4:15):

```
Checking ASE errorlog
Fri Apr 17 04:16:06 WAT 2020
Server=Sybaseprd
Errorlog=/mount/ASE-15_0/install/Sybaseprd.log
00:0006:00000:00061:2020/04/17 04:03:37.15 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0006:00000:00061:2020/04/17 04:03:37.15 server  Type '16' not allowed before login.
00:0004:00000:00668:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0004:00000:00668:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Type '16' not allowed before login.
00:0004:00000:00100:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0004:00000:00100:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Type '16' not allowed before login.
00:0012:00000:00000:2020/04/17 04:03:49.30 kernel  ksmask__rpacket: Invalid tdslength value 21536, kpid: 268895208
00:0003:00000:00932:2020/04/17 04:04:59.20 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0003:00000:00932:2020/04/17 04:04:59.20 server  Type '3' not allowed before login.
9 error lines found in errorlog for ASE server 'SybasePrd'
(end)
```

Incorrect behavior is as follows:

```
Checking ASE errorlog
Fri Apr 17 05:16:01 WAT 2020
Server=SybasePrd
Errorlog=/mount/ASE-15_0/install/Sybaseprd.log
00:0006:00000:00061:2020/04/17 04:03:37.15 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0006:00000:00061:2020/04/17 04:03:37.15 server  Type '16' not allowed before login.
00:0004:00000:00668:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0004:00000:00668:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Type '16' not allowed before login.
00:0004:00000:00100:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0004:00000:00100:2020/04/17 04:03:42.17 server  Type '16' not allowed before login.
00:0012:00000:00000:2020/04/17 04:03:49.30 kernel  ksmask__rpacket: Invalid tdslength value 21536, kpid: 268895208
00:0003:00000:00932:2020/04/17 04:04:59.20 server  Error: 1621, Severity: 18, State: 1
00:0003:00000:00932:2020/04/17 04:04:59.20 server  Type '3' not allowed before login.
9 error lines found in errorlog for ASE server 'SybasePRD'
(end)
```

Above job was triggered at 5:15 and there was no matching lines between 4:15 and 5:15 and hence nothing should have been reported. And as I mentioned earlier, this program kept on sending email till next 5 schedules i.e. unto 10:15 and stopped only when number of entries in the errorlog after above error was more than 40 or so.

So, desired outcome is to find the bug in the above shell script and fix it to check exactly for last one hour i.e. from last marker upto the last line in the errorlog and in case there are no entries, meaning there is no addition of lines from the last checking then then don't check or don't report anything as it happened below:

```
00:0004:00000:00974:2020/04/17 09:15:28.80 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
    00:0004:00000:00974:2020/04/17 09:15:38.80 server  _Marker_End_
    00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 10:15:59.92 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
    00:0005:00000:00514:2020/04/17 10:15:59.92 server  _Marker_End_
    00:0003:00000:00030:2020/04/17 11:16:01.51 server  _Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_
    00:0003:00000:00030:2020/04/17 11:16:01.51 server  _Marker_End_
```

Comment: That script needs to be completely rewritten as it contains several bugs and anti-patterns. Copy/paste it into http://www.shellcheck.net and it'll  tell you about some of them and see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization, http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for some others but there are yet more (some quite serious) not covered by those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've kinda stalled so lets see if we can get the ball rolling again. Assuming that the code you posted:

```
 LAST_MARKER=$(${AWK} '/'$MARKER'/ { a=NR } END { print a }' $LOGFILE_COPY)
  LAST_MARKER=`echo "$LAST_MARKER+0"|bs`
 if [ ! "$LAST_MARKER" = "" ]
   then
      sed "1,${LAST_MARKER}d" $LOGFILE_COPY > $TMP.x
      cp $TMP.x $LOGFILE_COPY
   fi
```

is intended to remove the text up to and including the last line containing $MARKER, if it exists, from $LOGFILE_COPY, here's how you'd really do that if you have `tac`:

```
tac "$LOGFILE_COPY" | awk -v m="$MARKER" '$0~m{exit} 1' | tac > "${TMP}.x" &&
mv "${TMP}.x" "$LOGFILE_COPY"
```

and if you don't have `tac` then the following 2-pass awk-only solution will run a bit slower and wouldn't work for input coming from a pipe but it will work for any size input file while the tac solution above MAY fail if the input file was absolutely massive:

```
awk -v m="$MARKER" 'NR==FNR{if ($0~m) a=NR; next} FNR>a' "$LOGFILE_COPY" "$LOGFILE_COPY" > "${TMP}.x" &&
mv "${TMP}.x" "$LOGFILE_COPY"
```

and if that's too slow (which I'd be surprised if it was), this might be a bit faster (it'll certainly be faster than the script you started with):

```
start=$(awk -v m="$MARKER" '$0~m{a=NR} END{printf "%d\n", a+1; exit (a?0:1)}' "$LOGFILE_COPY") &&
tail -n +"$start" "$LOGFILE_COPY" > "${TMP}.x" &&
mv "${TMP}.x" "$LOGFILE_COPY"
```

Does that solve your problem?

---

Aside: here's a start to how to modify [your original script](http://www.sypron.nl/check_errorlog.sh) to fix the most fundamental issues in it and make it easier to read:

```
#!/bin/sh

this_prog=$(basename "$0")

usage()
{
    echo "Usage:"
    echo " $this_prog <servername> <login> <passwd> [<errorlog-pathname> [\"all\"]]"
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Check parameters
if [ $# -lt 3 ] || [ $# -gt 5 ]
then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

srv=$1
login=$2
psswd=$3
logfile=$4
opt=$5

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Temp directory
tmp=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"/*; rmdir "$tmp"; exit' 0

logfile_copy="${tmp}/errlog"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Some contants; do NOT change these !
dft_mailprog="your_mail_program" #DO NOT CHANGE -- go to the next section
dft_dba_mail="you@yourcompany.com yourcollege@yourcompany.com" #DO NOT CHANGE
#                                                   -- go to the next section

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Some definitions
#
# mailprog must be set to your command-line mail program, like 'mail', 'mailx',
# etc. Later in this script, it is assumed that this mail program supports
# specifying the mail subject on the command line with the "-s" option.
# Should you use 'sendmail', you'll have to modify the script, or do without
# the mail subject, as 'sendmail' does not have this "-s" option.
# NT users may want to use 'ssmtp' (part of CygWin) as their mail
# program (also see comment below).
mailprog="$dft_mailprog"  # define your own setting here

# Define a list of people receiving results by email:
dba_mail="$dft_dba_mail"  # define your own setting here

skip_when_empty=NO # if YES, will not send mail when no errors were found

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The marker strings below can be set to any arbitrary string, as long
# as this is unique and does not appear in the errorlog as part of any
# error message.
# These strings should not be changed anymore once you've started using
# this script.
marker="_Marker_For_Checking_Errorlog_"        #do not change this !
marker2="_Marker_End_"                #do not change this !

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Change the below to 'gawk' (or 'nawk') if desired... This may be needed
# when hitting built-in max. string length limits in 'awk'. 'gawk' etc.
# tend to be more flexible.
AWK='awk'   # awk|gawk

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Check the mail program and email adresses have been defined
if [ "$mailprog" = "$dft_mailprog" ]
then
    echo ""
    echo "You must first define the variable 'mailprog' in this script;"
    echo "please set it to the name of your command-line mail program,"
    echo "like 'mail', 'mailx', etc."
    echo ""
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$dba_mail" = "$dft_dba_mail" ]
then
    echo ""
    echo "You must first define the variable 'dba_mail' in this script;"
    echo "please set it to a list of recipients."
    echo ""
    exit 1
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# First locate the server errorlog
rm -f "$logfile_copy"

if [ "$logfile" = "" ]
then
    # Pick up the server errorlog pathname; first check if this is 12.0
    # or later to determine the method for doing this
    #
    cat << --EOF-- > "${tmp}/vchk.sql"
select name from sysobjects  -- used for ASE version check
where name = "sysqueryplans"
go
dbcc traceon(3604)
go
dbcc resource -- contains errorlog pathname
go
--EOF--

    # The below isql session also doubles as an ASE access and
    # privilege check.
    # Using 'cat' and piping the SQL to isql is done to make it run on
    # Windows NT as well ('cos the NT version of 'isql' won't understand
    # Unix-style pathnames)
    #
    < "${tmp}/vchk.sql" isql -S"$srv" -U"$login" -P"$psswd" -w500 > "${tmp}/vchk"

    if grep -q "CT-LIBRARY error" "${tmp}/vchk"
    then
        cat "${tmp}/vchk"
        echo ""
        echo "*** Note: in case you cannot connect because the ASE server is down,"
        echo "*** you can also specify the errorlog pathname explicitly."
        echo ""
        usage
        exit 1
    fi

    if grep "You must have the following role(s) to" "${tmp}/vchk"
    then
        exit 1
    fi

    # 18-Sep-2001 Corrected the test below: it said "-ne 1" instead of "-eq 1",
    # causing it to not to identify version pre-12.0 correctly
    # (thanks to Jean Loesch)
    #
    if [ "$(grep -c "sysqueryplans" "${tmp}/vchk")" -eq 1 ]
    then
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # This is ASE 12.0+, so locate the errorlog through @@errorlog (this isn't
        # really necessary, as dbcc resource would still work fine), but let's do
        # it anyway for educational purposes ...

        cat << --EOF-- > "${tmp}/ataterrlog.sql"
print @@errorlog
go
--EOF--

        < "${tmp}/ataterrlog.sql" isql -S"$srv" -U"$login" -P"$psswd" > "${tmp}/ataterrlog"

        logfile=$( "$AWK" '{print $1}' "${tmp}/ataterrlog" )

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    else # not 12.0+

        # This is ASE pre-12.0, so locate the errorlog through dbcc resource (already
        # executed above)

        logfile=$( "$AWK" 'sub(/.*rerrfile=/,""){print $1}' "${tmp}/vchl" )

    fi

fi # if $logfile = ""

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Errorlog file name known now, check if it's there
if [ ! -f "$logfile" ]
then
    echo "Error accessing server errorlog file [$logfile] - file not found"
    echo "Note: this script must be run on the same host where the "
    echo "ASE errorlog file is located."
    exit 1
fi

cp "$logfile" "$logfile_copy"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Check option parameter
#
if [ "$opt" = "" ]
then
    scan_all=N
else
    scan_all=Y
    echo "Scanning the entire ASE errorlog."
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

if [ "$scan_all" = "N" ]
then

    # Skip the part of the errorlog until the last marker

    # Note: if the next line gives an error message, use a different shell

    last_marker=$("$AWK" -v marker="$marker" '$0 ~ marker { a=NR } END { print a+0 }' "$logfile_copy")
    if [ ! "$last_marker" = "" ]
    then
        sed "1,${last_marker}d" "$logfile_copy" > "${tmp}/x" &&
        cp "${tmp}/x" "$logfile_copy"
    fi

fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Create output file
{
    echo "Checking ASE errorlog"
    date
    echo "Server=$srv"
    echo "Errorlog=$logfile"
    echo ""
} > "${tmp}/out"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Finally... search for errors in the log file. The below set of search
# strings catches pretty much everything, but you can add any string here
# which you would also like to search for...
#
# Note that these strings indicate the presence of messages that should
# be investigated. Still, this may require further inspection of the
# errorlog, as more messages may be present which contain additional
# information.

grep -Ei '(warning|severity|fail|unmirror|mirror exit|not enough|error|suspect|corrupt|correct|deadlock|critical|allow|infect|error|full|problem|unable|not found|threshold|couldn|not valid|invalid|NO_LOG|logsegment|syslogs|stacktrace)' "$logfile_copy" |
grep -Evi '(successfull|_Marker_|(Suspect Granularity))' > "${tmp}/out2"

nrlines=$(wc -l "${tmp}/out2" | "$AWK" '{print $1}')

cat "${tmp}/out2" >> "${tmp}/out"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
echo "$nrlines error lines found in errorlog for ASE server '$srv'"

{
    echo ""
    echo "$nrlines error lines found in errorlog for ASE server '$srv'"
    echo ""
    echo "(end)"
} >> "${tmp}/out"

if [ "$skip_when_empty" = "NO" ] && [ "$nrlines" -eq 0 ]
then
    nrlines=1  # to force it into mailing anyway
fi

if [ "$nrlines" -gt 0 ]
then
    # Mail any error messages found to the list of recipients
    # (note: assumption is that the -s "subject" option is available for
    # your email program. Should you use "sendmail", it may not be
    # available, and you'd have to remove this option; when you're familiar
    # with 'sendmail', you can add the subject line yourself by inserting
    # header lines into the message file)
    #
    # Note for NT users: if you need a command-line mail program on NT,
    # consider 'ssmtp'. This is part of the CygWin package, which you need
    # anyway to run this script on NT. The download location for CygWin
    # is in the file header above.

    subj="Results of ASE errorlog check for '$srv'"
    "$mailprog" -s "$subj" "$dba_mail" < "${tmp}/out"
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

if [ "$scan_all" = "N" ]
then
    # Write a new marker to the server errorlog to indicate we got till here
    # Only do this when (i) no explicit errorlog pathname was specified and
    # (ii) only the last part of the log was scanned.

    cat << --EOF-- > "${tmp}/logprint.sql"
dbcc logprint ("$marker")
dbcc logprint ("$marker2") -- need a second line to avoid missing the last line
if @@error = 0 print "Writing marker to ASE errorlog."
-- note: in ASE 12.0, we could the more tidy "dbcc printolog(string)" instead
go
--EOF--

    < "${tmp}/logprint.sql" isql -S"$srv" -U"$login" -P"$psswd" | grep -Ev '(DBCC execution compl|(SA))'
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# end
#
```

There are other improvements that could be made and it's untested so it may have bugs but hopefully you can compare it to your original to see in what ways the original should be changed.

Comment: Its working after changing print a+1 to printf "%d\n", a+1. I can upvote your answer only once and can accept only once however you have helped me much more than that. THANKS A TON.

Comment: You're welcome. Please do check your full original script against the links in [the comment I left about it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580887/need-help-on-sed-awk-command-shell-script-for-checking-sybase-errorlog/580985?noredirect=1#comment1081549_580887) as it has a lot of issues that will bite you one day and in cryptic, possibly silent, hard to reproduce ways depending on input data, the contents of the directory you run it from, environment settings, etc., etc.

Comment: I just took a look at that full script (http://www.sypron.nl/check_errorlog.sh) again and noticed `egrep -vi '(successfull` - that's not how you spell `successful` so you probably should modify that unless it's mis-spelled in your input files too.